# How do I destroy the main screen after successful login

Tags: python, tkinter

I have read a post that is closely similar to mine but I cannot input said function into my code so I am here to ask. I am doing a login screen and I would like to destroy all screens when I have a successful login.

This is the main screen :

```
def main_screen():
    global screen
    screen = Tk()
    screen.geometry("500x450")
    screen.title("COVID-19 VACCINE REGISTRATION PROGRAM")
    screen.config(bg="lavender", border ="10",borderwidth="15")
    Label(text = "USER LOGIN AND SIGN UP" , bg = "darkblue", fg="white" , height ="4", width ="400", font =("Times New Roman", 15)).pack() #label
    Label(text = "").pack()  #.pack() => to put widgets in frame.
    Button(text = "LOGIN ", bg = "firebrick", fg = "white",  height = "4", width ="30", font =("Times New Roman", 15) ,command = login ).pack() #login button
    Label(text = "").pack()    #empty for space
    Button(text = "REGISTER", bg ="firebrick", fg ="white" , height = "4", width ="30", font =("Times New Roman", 15), command = register ).pack() #register new account button

    screen.mainloop()
```

This is the verification login :

```
def login_succesful():
    global screen_3
    screen_3=Toplevel(screen)
    Label(screen_3,text="").pack()
    screen_3.title("Succesful login attempt")            #to create a pop up showing login attempt is succesful
    screen_3.geometry("250x200")
    screen_3.config(bg="lavender")
    Label(screen_3,text="").pack()
    Label(screen_3,text = "LOGIN ATTEMPT SUCCESFUL", fg = "green" ,font = ("Times New Roman",12)).pack()
    Label(screen_3,text="").pack()
    Button(screen_3,text = "Done", command = delete2 , bg = "maroon" , fg = "white").pack()
```

and this is the delete def :

```
def delete2():
    screen_3.destroy()  
    main_screen.destroy()
```

and the error I get is the same to the post but as I said I am not able to implement the said suggestion into my code.

The error is :
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'destroy'

Comment: `main_screen` is the function that created the main screen, not the main screen itself. The screen is the local variable `screen` inside that function, and it's not accessible outside the function. I'd suggest `return`ing that variable and call `screen.mainloop()` from the caller. You then have that value in your code and can use it to destroy that screen.

Comment: Oh thank you, I have solved the problem.

Comment: If you solved the problem, please post and accept an answer, so that other users can benefit from it. It's okay, in fact we encourage you, to answer your own question.

Answer (score 0):

main_screen was a function. Use `screen.destroy()`